# mmap only works on small files?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, mmap

I'm trying to map a file from local disk into memory so my program can access the file content. When mmap is called on a file (just under 100kB in size), I view the memory in the debugger starting at the address returned by mmap, and the memory content does not match the file content (both viewed in Hexadecimal). This is **not** a byte-swapping issue. Only the first 2 bytes in memory and the actual file match and the rest of the content do not.

When I repeat the same thing on a small file containing a string (ex: "hello world"), then the memory as viewed in the debugger matches exactly the content of the file (again viewed in Hex).

I tried using MAP_PRIVATE instead of MAP_SHARED but same result. How can I get this to work with my bigger file?

I'm working in Ubuntu 17.10 with Eclipse 4.7.2 + CDT and debugging with GDB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
    void* MapAddr = NULL;
    char* pData = NULL;
    struct stat FileProps;
    int FileDes = 0;
    const char* fileNameAndPath = "/home/Test/testfile.txt";

    FileDes = open(fileNameAndPath, O_RDWR);

    if (FileDes != -1)
    {
        if (fstat(FileDes, &FileProps) == 0)
        {
            MapAddr = mmap(NULL, FileProps.st_size, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, FileDes, 0);
            if (MapAddr == (void*) -1)
            {
                std::cout << "init: mmap failed" << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    pData = (char*) MapAddr;
    std::cout << pData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

13:10:42 **** Build of configuration Debug for project mmapTest ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/mmapTest.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/mmapTest.d" -MT"src/mmapTest.o" -o "src/mmapTest.o" "../src/mmapTest.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/mmapTest.cpp

Building target: mmapTest
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "mmapTest"  ./src/mmapTest.o
Finished building target: mmapTest

13:10:46 Build Finished (took 4s.438ms)

Comment: I suppose you are aware that the program uses non-standard features. Is there some reason you want to read the file into mapped memory rather that memory from the heap? Doing the latter is easy and can be done portably.

Comment: Thanks for including a compilable code sample. Can you also show how you reproduce the problem?

Comment: @thatotherguy - It's not compilable on all platforms.

Comment: But does the program work? `nmap()` works via paging, and the debugger may or may nor force that.

Comment: JD - is mmap non-standard, or something else I'm doing? I'm trying to port the Windows function CreateFileMapping to Linux. My goal is to take data out of a file, map it into memory and then map that memory to structure pointers. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: EJP - It appears to work in GDB. It is mmap(), not nmap().

Comment: TOG - To reproduce the problem I just run the debugger. I seem to get the same data every time when I view the memory address returned by mmap().

Comment: @JiveDadson It compiles on the platform described in the question. I don't understand what kind of point you're trying to make or why it's helpful in this case

Comment: Looks like your analysis is incorrect. It should work as expected.

Comment: @MrB I suspect you do more than just run the debugger, because `gdb<enter>` doesn't do much. Maybe you run `gdb ./mmapTest` followed by `break 32` and `run`, then you `print pData` and it shows what instead of what? If so, that would be a good addition to the question. This would help make the question easier to answer now, and more helpful to future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined the reason that the memory content (as viewed in the GDB debugger) did not match the actual file content, after mmap() was run, is that the file that I mapped was not ANSI-encoded. So the debugger was showing the correct data as Linux thought it should be. After saving the file (in textpad) with ANSI format, the binary content of the file as viewed in Linux was the same as the binary content as viewed in Windows. No code change was needed. The problem was with the file being mapped. And contrary to one of the comments, the GDB debugger IS ABLE to show ALL the mapped file data with the memory viewer at the address returned by mmap() - I've confirmed this for files up to 100KB.

Answer (score 1):

`mmap()` does not actually read the whole file into memory, nor actually allocates file size RAM amount. It just allocates virtual address space big enough to "fit" the file in it.

It works by using page faults, when you try to read some area of the file then the actual RAM will be allocated (or some other pages reused) and data for certain amount of pages read from file into memory.

You will hardly ever get the whole file loaded into ram with `mmap()`. But your program should work, whenever you try to read or write data (from program, **not** from debugger) everything will work just fine.

---

And, yes, the most important thing, `mmap()` works the same way as `CreateFileMapping()` so you should be OK porting the code.

Comment: I wonder how can GDB load memory without causing a page fault?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response BJovke. Let me confirm that it works without using the debugger (I'll try to map some structures or something to the file content and try to print them). BRB.

Comment: All of the debuggers use special CPU instructions which have been created just for debugging. Most probably there's an option for debugger not to cause page faults nor any other side effects caused by it running. The idea is to mimic the real working environment for the program.

Comment: I think the problem of seeing unexpected memory in the debugger in the Linux program is that I'm mapping a file that is used in a Windows application and most likely is encoded for Windows. Does this sound like a likely explanation? (i.e: using mmap in Linux to map a file encoded in Windows, and seeing the wrong content. In the Windows debugger the memory matches exactly the file content). Sorry I know very little when it comes to file encodings between different OSs (UTF8, etc).

Comment: The `CreateFileMapping()` maybe initially loads larger part of the file into RAM, it all depends on how it is internally implemented. If this initial buffer is larger than your file then the whole file is read. For you this doesn't matter, you will always get your contents when you try to read the data. Don't try to rely on inner workings of both `mmap()` and `CreateFileMapping()`, they both guarantee you that your program will work as expected.